# mod-rewrite to remove tracking code from the end of urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I write a mod-rewrite to remove an old tracking code after image urls. I would like to send requests for

```
 www.myurl.com/blah/image.jpg%12345
```

to

```
 www.myurl.com/blah/image.jpg
```

The %12345 tracking code is always the same.

Comment: please at the very least show your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The %12345 tracking code is always the same.

At the start of that string `%12` is urlencoded as an unprintable character, but `mod_rewrite` treats it like a `_`. So you would have to inspect the `REQUEST_URI` for `_345` and strip it out accordingly.

> %3F345 is used in the URL.

If the tracking code is `%3F345`, then the `%3F` is urlencoded as a `?` and should be detected as a query string. However, the `mod_rewrite` doesn't catch this it seems, so I used two checks for your case - one for `?` and one for `%3F`. This will work if the `?` is encoded or not:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^345 [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \%3F345 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Inputs:

> http://www.myurl.com/blah/image.jpg?345
>   http://www.myurl.com/blah/image.jpg%3F345
>   http://www.myurl.com/blah/image.jpg%3F345&param=value

Rewrite:

> http://www.myurl.com/blah/image.jpg

NOTE: You *cannot* experiment with it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) because `%{THE_REQUEST}` is not supported. I tested this on one of my live servers to verify it works.

Comment: Thanks that was very useful. Made me realise that the tracking code wasn't random characters but beginning with %3F (not %12) was replacing a ?. The following works in the tester but not a browser if %3F345 is used in the URL rather than ?345 ` RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^345$ 
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent] `

Comment: I updated my answer with something that should work in your browser, because it works in mine on my own server.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you, I really appreciate your time and effort.